# Notifications for significantly edited answers/questions

Tags: feature-request, edits, notifications

As far as I am aware, when a user edits either a question or an answer, someone following that question or answer does not receive a notification.

However, I suggest that in some cases it might be pertinent to notify the user for significant edits.

Perhaps the system can automatically determine when edits are significant based on amount of characters added/changed or perhaps even give an option to the editor to mark the edit as important?

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to see a notification to the author for any edit (or accepted edit, probably not for suggested). For those who are making mistakes, whether that's mistagging, starting with a greeting, not formatting their code or whatever, seeing someone fixed it might be ilustrative. And understanding how edits increase answers could also follow from that notification.

And of course, if an edit is one the author disagrees with, it seems only fair to let them know it has happened.